# select a value from dropdown list in html5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I m new here and in HTML.Well I have to select many values from different areas (eg dropdown list, date input type, time input type etc) and compare them with a table. It select the value right,but it appears only for a sec in the screen and then it disappears!It seems that my Chrome refreshes!This is what i ve done till now..

//inside javascript

```
function Searching()
    {
        var a=document.getElementById('movies');
        var selMov=a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
        var b=document.getElementById('areas');
        var selAr=b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
        var c=document.getElementById('dat').type='date';
        var d=document.getElementById("tim").type='time';
        var rows=document.getElementById('dataProgram').getElementsByTagName('tr');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=selMov;

    }
```

And i have this `<p id="demo"></p>` to appear the result.

Comment: How is the function called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not cancelling the event that triggers the function. So the page is reloading.

You need to `return false` or call [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault)

Edit:

based on the comment

```
<button type="submit" id="but" onclick="Searching(); return false;">Search</button>
```

Comment: i tried with this,but it didn't work.i found this code,with no return false and is ok. <code> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to check the age.</p>

Age:<input id="age" value="18" />
<p>Old enough to vote?</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var age,voteable;
age=document.getElementById("age").value;
voteable=(age<18)?"Too young":"Old enough";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=voteable;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

<code>

Comment: How are you triggering the method `Searching()`?

Comment: <button type="submit" id="but" onclick="Searching()">Search</button>

Comment: and that is why. A button does not post back. A submit button does!

Comment: i add a loop and  an if ,to have more than 1 results back.It works,but i want to have the results in radiobuttons so the user can choose only one. Is this possibly?